# Change a functions "this" value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

I'm building a library with a some methods and I have a method `extend` and a method `load`. I'd LIKE it to work like this:

```
Core.extend('name',function(message){
  this.innerHTML = message;
});
```

Then to actually run this you'd do:

```
Core.load('name','Hey!');
```

`Core.extend()` creates a `<div>` element with a unique id based on the name. I want to make `this` == the generated `<div>`.

I know about `.call()` and `.apply()`, obviously, but it doesn't change `this` it only changes the callback params in extend. Here's the code for extend and load:

**Core.extend()**

```
var extend = function(name,func){
  name = name || '';
  func = func || function(){};
  if(typeof extensions[name] == 'undefined'){
    extensions[name] = func;
  }
  else{
    if(errors){
      throw new Error('Core extend() error: the extension "'+name+'" already exists');
    }
  }
}
```

**Core.load()**

Note this is the main line: `extensions[name].call(this,widgetElement,params);`

```
var load = function(name,params,sel){
  name = name || '';
  params = params || '';
  sel = sel || '';
  if(typeof extensions[name]  !== 'undefined'){
    var widgetElement = document.createElement(settings.widgetWrapperElement);
    widgetElement.setAttribute('id',settings.prefixOnWidgetId+name);
    sel.appendChild(widgetElement);
    extensions[name].call(this,widgetElement,params);
  }
  else{
    if(errors){
      throw new Error('Core load() error: the extension "'+name+'" doesn\'t exist');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Function.call` function's first argument should be what you want to set as the `this` object.

That means, you should change

```
extensions[name].call(this, widgetElement, params);
```

to

```
extensions[name].call(widgetElement, params);
```

in order to pass `widgetElement` as the `this` object.

Comment: YES! Duh! I've always thought the first param was "what to modify". I.e. if I did `.call(widgetElement,'duh')` then in my callback the first param would equal `duh`. Thanks :) P.S. Ill mark as correct once the time goes by...

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `this` set appropriately, you execute the callback function with either `.call()` or `.apply()` and pass in the `this` that you want.

So, inside of `Core.extend()` or `Core.load()`, when you are about to call the passed in function, you would use `fn.call(xxx, message)` where fn is the function passed to the `Core.extend()` as a parameter, `xxx` was the div element you had just created.

I don't follow exactly what all you're trying to do, but you set the `this` point with either `.call()` or `.apply()`.  You can see how they work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply).  In your code, it looks like you should change this:

```
extensions[name].call(this,widgetElement,params);
```

to this:

```
extensions[name].call(widgetElement, params);
```

since the first argument to `.call` is what you want the `this` pointer to be and the second argument is what you want to be passed to the function and your function in your example only takes one parameter so I presume that's all you need.